# Symmetry not working in Weight paint mode

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights

Anyone would know why when I try to weight paint, I can't use the symmetry option to mirror vertex groups?
For context I used Rigify and have now this message that says: "This property is for internal use only and can't be edited". When I edit or paint my vertices symmetry functions properly.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Weight paint mode only X AXIS Simmetry is available, so if you need simmetry rotate your model 90 degrees on Z axis and Apply the rotation (Ctrl A).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thought I was maybe missing something.

Comment: The gradient feature does not seem to be working for symmetry at all, or am I missing something?